# Mix JOOQ query with JDBC transaction

Tags: java, jdbc, jooq

I have a use case where I would like to mix a jdbc transaction with jooq context.

The JDBC code looks like that:

```
  public void inTransaction(InTransaction lambda) {
    DataSource ds = dataSource.get();
    try (Connection connection = ds.getConnection()) {
      try {
        logger.info("set autocommit to false");
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        try (Statement statement = connection.createStatement()) {
          lambda.execute(statement);
          logger.info("commiting transaction");
          connection.commit();
        }
      } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        logger.info("rolling back transaction");
        connection.rollback();
        throw e;
      } finally {
        logger.info("set autocommit to true");
        connection.setAutoCommit(true);
      }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      throw new TilerException(e);
    }
  }

  @FunctionalInterface
  public interface InTransaction {
    void execute(Statement statement) throws SQLException;
  }
```

And I would like the `lambda` parameter to be able to work with both jdbc and jooq.

For jdbc using a statement is pretty straight-forward. For example something like this [tutorail](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-transactions.htm):

```
 inTransaction(stmt -> {
   String SQL = "INSERT INTO Employees  " +
                "VALUES (106, 20, 'Rita', 'Tez')";
   stmt.executeUpdate(SQL);
   String SQL = "INSERTED IN Employees  " +
                "VALUES (107, 22, 'Sita', 'Singh')";
   stmt.executeUpdate(SQL);
 });
```

In order to execute jooq queries on the same transaction I have to obtain a context. I found an [api](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.1/manual/sql-building/dsl-context/) to get a DSLContext from datasource/connection.
What is not clear to me is if/how to create a jooq `DSLContext` from a statement?

Comment: I don't understand your question. when creating a DslContext with DSL.using you have to pass the connection to the configuration. and the commit happens on the connection.

Comment: I want to pass it a statement instead of connection. I am already using that statement to run other queries/updates using jdbc.

Comment: I'm sorry but your code doesn't make sense as you could only execute on statement per transaction. It would be the same as auto commit

Comment: Beside that there is an open issue: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/3715

Comment: I added an example how I am using that method. The same statement is used in multiple queries on the same transaction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### A solution to the problem you described

You can do all of this with jOOQ's transaction API:

```java
// Create this ad-hoc, or inject it, or whatever
DSLContext ctx = DSL.using(dataSource, dialect);
```

And then:

```java
public void inJDBCTransaction(InJDBCTransaction lambda) {
    ctx.transaction(config -> {
        config.dsl().connection(connection -> {
            try (Statement statement = connection.createStatement()) {
                lambda.execute(statement);
            }
        });
    });
}

public void inJOOQTransaction(InJOOQTransaction lambda) {
    ctx.transaction(config -> lambda.execute(config.dsl()));
}

@FunctionalInterface
public interface InJDBCTransaction {
    void execute(Statement statement) throws SQLException;
}

@FunctionalInterface
public interface InJOOQTransaction {
    void execute(DSLContext ctx);
}
```

Your final code:

```java
inJDBCTransaction(stmt -> {
    String SQL = "INSERT INTO Employees  " +
                 "VALUES (106, 20, 'Rita', 'Tez')";
    stmt.executeUpdate(SQL);
    String SQL = "INSERTED IN Employees  " +
                 "VALUES (107, 22, 'Sita', 'Singh')";
    stmt.executeUpdate(SQL);
});

inJOOQTransaction(ctx -> {
    ctx.insertInto(EMPLOYEES).values(106, 20, "Rita", "Tez").execute();
    ctx.insertInto(EMPLOYEES).values(107, 22, "Sita", "Singh").execute();
});
```

I'm not too convinced about the need for this abstraction over jOOQ and JDBC. jOOQ never hides JDBC from you. You can always access the JDBC API as shown above when using the [`DSLContext.connection()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#connection(org.jooq.ConnectionRunnable)) method. So, as shown above:

- The jOOQ transaction API does exactly what you're planning to do. Wrap a lambda in a transactional context, commit if it succeeds, rollback if it fails (your version's rollback doesn't work because it catches the wrong exception).
- If the "JDBC escape hatch" is needed, jOOQ can offer that

#### Side note

In many RDBMS, you don't want to run queries on a static JDBC [`Statement`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Statement.html). You'll want to use [`PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) instead because:

- You'll profit from execution plan caching (and less contention on the cache)
- You'll avoid syntax errors (in case your real query is dynamic)
- You'll avoid SQL injection trouble

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the query string from jOOQ you can call

```
String sqlString = query.getSQL()
```

and then use this string in your statement:

```
stmt.executeUpdate(sqlString);
```

Comment: thanks, this is a good solution for updates. In my case I also have queries (where jooq parses the result and creates objects) and I don't see how I can use that to do so.

Comment: I would do it the other way around. Use jOOQ for everything. You can also pass SQL string to jOOQ to get exectued.